# Combining non-word and underscore patterns to match any non-alphanumeric characters

Tags: javascript, regex

In javascript, I want to weed out all non-alphanumeric characters.  here's my code:

```
function (inpt) {
        return inpt.replace(/[^\w]/gi, "").replace(/_/g, "");
    }
```

This code works 100% correct.  Removes all non-alphanumeric characters.

The `\w` still allows underscore, which is why I chained two `replace` statements together.

I then tried combining the Regular Expressions like this, and now underscores are no longer filtered.

```
function (inpt) {
        return inpt.replace(/[^\w_]/gi, "");     // note:  added _
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use `[\W_]` instead. The i flag isn't needed.

Comment: It is saying "not \w" or "not _"

Comment: @epascarello - thanks, I wish I could up-vote your comment more than once.   (-:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `[^\w_]` pattern represents a [***negated character* class**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) that matches any char but a word (letter, digit or `_`) and `_` chars.

The `[^\w]` pattern is equal to `\W`. So, you may use

```
/[\W_]/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gVsqnX/1).

Here, `[\W_]` is a *positive* [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) that matches either a non-word char or a `_`.

JS demo:

```js
var str = "some%_1string*";
console.log(str.replace(/[\W_]+/g, ''));
```

Note that `.replace(/[\W_]+/g, '')` removes the chars you need a bit quicker than `.replace(/[\W_]/g, '')` since `+` quantifier matches 1+ consecutive occurrences of matching characters and removes them all in one go.

Comment: Thanks.  I was getting confused by the '^'... thought it might have been the start of the string.  If you combine epascarello's comment into your answer, I can accept your answer as final.

Comment: @Joe Nie ma za co :)